# Loop into a other loop question isn`t loop from beginning

Tags: automation, rpa

I make a loop into a other loop but when the second loop is ready it doesn`t start by line 1 it is going to start line 2 so it looks then in the wrong file.
What is going wrong?

```
1   Read From CSV file: "Z:\Business_files\Input\export.csv" Delimiter: "Comma" Header: "Yes" Trim Leading Space: "No" Trim Trailing Space: "No" Session: 'Default'
2   Start Loop "Each row in a CSV/Text file of Session: Default"
3        Variable Operation: $Filedata Column(3)$ To $v_ID_Ovze$
4        Message Box: "$v_ID_Ovze$"
5        Read From CSV file: "Z:\Business_files\TableFolder\Table.csv" Delimiter: "Comma" Header: "No" Trim Leading Space: "No" Trim Trailing Space: "No" Session: 'Default'
6        Start Loop "Each row in a CSV/Text file of Session: Default"
7             Variable Operation: $Filedata Column(6)$ To $v_Count_Row_Ovze$
8             Message Box: "$v_Count_Row_Ovze$"
9        End Loop
10  End Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a different Session name for the loops. That might be causing the problem